# Query optimization in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have rather simple query with big total runtime. Can you advise me how can I optimize it?

Here is explain analyze: http://explain.depesz.com/s/9xC5

query:

```
select wpis_id from spoleczniak_oznaczone
where etykieta_id in(
  select tag_id
  from spoleczniak_subskrypcje
  where postac_id = 376476
  );
```

spoleczniak_oznaczone:

```
 Column    |  Type   |                             Modifiers
-------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer | not null default nextval('spoleczniak_oznaczone_id_seq'::regclass)
 etykieta_id | integer | not null
 wpis_id     | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "spoleczniak_oznaczone_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "spoleczniak_oznaczone_etykieta_id" btree (etykieta_id)
    "spoleczniak_oznaczone_wpis_id" btree (wpis_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "spoleczniak_oznaczone_etykieta_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (etykieta_id) REFERENCES    spoleczniak_etykiety(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "spoleczniak_oznaczone_wpis_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (wpis_id) REFERENCES spoleczniak_tablica(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

spoleczniak_subskrypcje:

```
  Column   |  Type   |                              Modifiers
-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer | not null default nextval('spoleczniak_subskrypcje_id_seq'::regclass)
 postac_id | integer | not null
 tag_id    | integer | not null
Indexes:
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_postac_id" btree (postac_id)
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_postac_tag" btree (postac_id, tag_id)
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_tag_id" btree (tag_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_postac_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (postac_id) REFERENCES postac_postacie(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "spoleczniak_subskrypcje_tag_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES spoleczniak_etykiety(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Please also add the actual query.

Comment: ... and the resulting query plan, please... Does your table have valid statistics ? did you perform any tuning on the database settings ?

Comment: @wildplasser: the query plan is there. A link to explain.depesz.com

Comment: Which Postgres version is that? On 9.2 I would have expected it to make use of an index only scan on the index `spoleczniak_subskrypcje_postac_tag`. Also your row estimates are a bit off. So maybe it *is* a problem with statistics

Comment: If you read the plan carefully, you could see that your statistics are off. Run `vacuum analyze;` on both tables.

Comment: I have autovacuum daemon turned on. I did vacuum analyze on both tables anyway - and still no luck. It's 9.2.7, @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: BTW: You dont need the (four?) extra indexes that are covered by FK constraints: in Postgres a FK automagically implies an index.

Comment: @wildplasser: Postgres does not automatically create an index when you declare a FK constraint - and even if it did they would most probably show up as regular indexes as seen in the question when you do a describe in `psql`. But I do agree that `spoleczniak_subskrypcje_postac_id` is not needed

Comment: Oops. I stand corrected. Again.

Answer (score 2):

From the Query Plan, most of the time seems to be involved in working out the IN part of the where clause. Proper indexes seem to be used.

```
select o.wpis_id 
from spoleczniak_oznaczone o
inner join spoleczniak_subskrypcje s on s.tag_id = o.etykieta_id
where s.postac_id = 376476
```

...looks to be functionally the same but tries it in a different way and could generate a different query plan.

Also, as @wildplasser says, make sure statistics are up-to-date, and indexes defragmented (don't know how to do those in PostgreSQL myself).

EDIT: as @a_horse_with_no_name says in the comment below, the query I've suggested can return duplicates where the original wouldn't. Without knowing your data I don't know whether it will or not. That's a warning to bear in mind.

Comment: A join is not necessarily a replacement for an `IN` condition.

Comment: I don't think so. `postac_id` is not unique, neither is `tag_id`. So a single `postac_id` could return the same `tag_id` multiple times and then the result of the join will be different to the result of an `IN` query.

Comment: ...and I missed something. You're right - Thanks! I'll annotate the answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: in this case you are wrong: `in (...)` removes duplicates (and NULLs) from the subquery's result before using it in the main query.

Comment: @wildplasser: exactly, and that's why the join will return something different.

Comment: After rereading the OQ, it seems you were right. (I was assuming that a FK or candidate key was referenced in the subquery: these (Polish?) names are hard to read ...) The statistics still look terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you preferred using `in` and a subquery to:

```
select wpis_id 
from spoleczniak_oznaczone, spoleczniak_subskrypcje
where etykieta_id = tag_id 
and postac_id = 376476
```

I would guess a simple join might be simpler for the query optimiser.

Comment: To the OP: If you read the plan carefully, you could see that your statistics are off. Run `vacuum analyze;` on both tables.

Comment: I did. Before running that query.

Comment: Seems illogical: the estimated number of rows in the subquery is still terribly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* be equivalent (and in most cases will generate the same query plan)

```
SELECT so.wpis_id
FROM spoleczniak_oznaczone so
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM spoleczniak_subskrypcje ss
  WHERE ss.tag_id= so.etykieta_id
  AND so.postac_id = 376476
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this index:

```
"spoleczniak_oznaczone_etykieta_id" btree (etykieta_id)
```

with an index on `(etykieta_id, wpis_id)`. This way DB could perform index-only scan (without fetching whole rows from table which costs access time).

Comment: It's faster, but not fast enough (original query ~800 ms, after this index change ~500 ms).

Comment: Can you attach explain plan with BUFFERS parameter? Your query returns >500.000 rows and this may be the cause.

Comment: It does now perform index-only scan, but it needs to loop 23 times through it. Shouldn't a pair `(postac_id, tag_id)` in spoleczniak_subskrypcje be unique? If I get it correctly, this table is for people's subscriptions on tags, right? If that's true, then you may try @simonatrcl query - replace `IN (...)` with join. This may eliminate nested loop.